# Custom UIPickerView in MonoTouch.Dialog?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, uipickerview, monotouch.dialog

I've tried creating my own version of a UIPickerView element for MonoTouch Dialog, but it was to no avail.  Is there some form of it already implemented within `MonoTouch.Dialog` or a way I could edit a `DateTimeElement` to act as a UIPickerView with my custom entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheesebaron has done this - see the code and discussion in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/pull/25

The base of this code is indeed based around the uipickerview inside the dateelement